# android listview scroll past top

Tags: android, listview, animation, scroll

Does anyone know how to achieve the "scroll past top" functionality that you see in some apps (like the HTC Sense email app for example) where when you scroll up to the top of the list and try to scroll up past that, it appears to pull down, and when you release it springs back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh. I think it implements the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: definitely what i was after... ~2 years ago in 2.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to achieve this look with the default ListViews.  Everyone who has done this implemented their own custom ListView widget that supports this functionality.

Comment: Nope, I haven't done it.  But I've talked to developers who have, and they said they had to roll their own implementations.

Comment: dang.  do you know if they built their own listview from scratch? or did they just extend the existing listview?

Comment: The one that I talked to in detail said they built it entirely from scratch, but then I think they did that with the many widgets they had so it doesn't surprise me.  That said, Android is open source, so it's not hard to build off of the original ListView.